# companion object are overused in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Here I have java code

```
  private static void content() {}
```

and I convert to Kotlin it shows it becomes

```
companion object {

    private fun content() {}
}
```

I am wondering should I keep it in companion object or should I remove companion object?

Comment: Kotlin companion = Java static.

Comment: I know about so you think it is ok to keep companion object or it is better simple private fun ?

Comment: Do you know how `static` works? You can access to them without creating the object. So for example you are NOT creating `ApiServices` or NetworkRepository` to access some field with `url` `token` or `headers`.

Comment: If you can have it as simple private fun it's unclear why it was static in Java in the first place.

Comment: Kotlin companion object is not the same thing as a Java static. Top level functions and properties are compiled to Java statics. Companion objects are compiled to entirely separate classes, and an instance of the class is instantiated when it is first accessed. They are only the similar in the way their members are accessed. Your code will be lighter weight if you don't use the companion object, although in most cases the difference is probably insignificant.

Comment: If you create a companion object and access a member of it, you aren't creating an instance of the "owner" of the companion, but you *are* creating a singleton instance of the companion class. With a Java static, this would not be the case.

Answer (score 1):

The companion object is a singleton, and its members can be accessed directly via the name of the containing class (although you can also insert the name of the companion object if you want to be explicit about accessing the companion object)

A companion object is initialized when the class is loaded (typically the first time it's referenced by other code that is being executed), in a thread-safe manner. You can omit the name, in which case the name defaults to Companion. A class can only have one companion object, and companion objects can not be nested.

```
class Car(val horsepowers: Int) {
companion object Factory {
    val cars = mutableListOf<Car>()

    fun makeCar(horsepowers: Int): Car {
        val car = Car(horsepowers)
        cars.add(car)
        return car
    }
}
```

}

```
val car = Car.makeCar(150)
println(Car.Factory.cars.size)
```

The advantage of companion objects have over static members is that they can inherit from other classes or implement interfaces and generally behave like any other singleton.